# How do I properly implement mysite.com/username without interfering with my pages?

Tags: php, mysql, url

This has always baffled me, I understand the concept of "pretty URLs" yet cannot grasp how I can implement this without potentially obstructing the layout of my site.

I understand that I can just not allow people to have usernames like "messages" so it won't interfere with a /messages page, however I have no idea what types of pages I'll be adding to my site later... So for example if I wanted to have mysite.com/hub/ (I'm not a fan of hub.mysite.com) and someone registered the name "hub" what can I do about that? Am I just screwed at this point, needing to either rename it or force the user to change their name? If anyone can give me advice about how I should properly go about this I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Typically, if your site has a structure at the root level, you wouldn't give users URLs at the root. Instead use `/users/username`  Otherwise, you need rewrite rules at the web server level (not PHP) which account for all other non-username cases. Some application frameworks will handle this as well - known controllers get routed accordingly, and then by default route everything else to search for a username, finally 404 if no user is found.

Comment: @Michael Hey I didn't see your comment as I was typing my answer, but you said essentially the same thing. I'll delete my answer if you decide to answer yourself, since you were first.

Comment: A lot of sites give users the first path segment but move their sections into subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also see this method as being problematic. Instead of mysite.com/some-user, how about mysite.com/users/some-user? That way they can't interfere with the rest of your site.

Comment: Or namespace all your application URLs into, say, `/app/...` and don't let anyone use that as a username.

Comment: @muistooshort That could work too. But if the OP is worried about interferences, then I'm guessing his site is not structured that way.

Comment: The site's not live so it's not a big deal to do some restructuring, but I really wanted to avoid /user/

Comment: Agreed. You're going to run into problems if you expect to add more URLs and apps to your site going forward and you are allowing user-provided names to construct the URLs at that level. I would also suggest either using "users", "members", "community" or something to separate them into their own namespace. You can do redirects in the short term to make the transition go more smoothly.

Comment: @Ian Personally, I think it's better that way. I can see muistooshort's point, but then you'd have to worry about preventing users from using certain names.

Comment: @Ian: You could also reserve something short (say `/a/...`) for your application and make every use longer names. This can also make it easier to add multi-language support through `/en`, `/ja`, ...